# Animate elements with the same class individually with waypoints.js and anime.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints, anime.js, waypoint

I have this script that animates a title when it enters the viewport with viewport.js and anime.js:

```
$(".title").waypoint(function() {
anime.timeline({loop: false})
  .add({
    targets: '.title span',
    rotateY: [-90, 0],
    duration: 1300,
    delay: (el, i) => 45 * i
  });
}, {
            offset: '100%'
});
```

When I use the .title class multiple times, all the titles will animate again when another enters the viewport. Do I make a copy of the script with .title1, .title2 etc? Or is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `.title span` selector in `targets` selects all the elements.

To select only the element relevant to the waypoint which has been triggered, use `this.element`. From there you can find the `span` element(s) to call `anime` on. Try this:

```js
$(".title").waypoint(function() {
  anime.timeline({
    loop: false
  }).add({
    targets: this.element.querySelectorAll('span'),
    rotateY: [-90, 0],
    duration: 1300,
    delay: (el, i) => 45 * i
  });
}, {
  offset: '100%'
});
```